# R converts as.Date to different data type when assigning to vector or dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to store Date objects in a vector and a data.frame respectively.
However there seems to be some trouble. When I assign the object to the vector it seems to be converted to a numeric data type. The following Code

```
print(as.Date("11-Jan-2011",format="%d-%b-%Y"))
test_v <-c()
test_v[1]<-as.Date("11-Jan-2011",format="%d-%b-%Y")
print(test_v)
print(str(test_v))
```

gives the output

```
[1] "2011-01-11"
[1] 14985
num 14985
NULL
```

Similarly when I try to assign a Date object to a specific row and column of a data.frame it again is converted, this time however to a character.

```
test_df <- data.frame(a=c(1:3))
test_df$b <- 999
test_df[1,]$b <- "any string"
test_df[2,]$b <- 2
test_df[3,]$b <- as.Date("11-Jan-2011",format="%d-%b-%Y")
print(test_df$b)
str(test_df$b)
str(test_df[3,]$b)
```

results in

```
[1] "any string" "2"          "14985"  
chr [1:3] "any string" "2" "14985"
chr "14985"
```

Assigning the date object to the entire column of a data.frame seems to work however.

```
test_df$c <- as.Date("11-Jan-2011",format="%d-%b-%Y")
str(test_df)
```

results in

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
$ a: int  1 2 3
$ b: chr  "any string" "2" "14985"
$ c: Date, format: "2011-01-11" "2011-01-11" "2011-01-11"
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Date objects are defined as the number of integer days since the beginning (Jan 1, 1970).
Vectors and data frame columns *can only store 1 type of object*.

Thus when you attempt to store a Date object in an existing data structure, the Date objects get converted to the most lowest common object type.  In the case above, Date Objects get converted to Integers and then to Character strings.

To retain the date formatting use the `format` function before the assignment.

```
test_df <- data.frame(a=c(1:3))
test_df$b <- 999
test_df[1,]$b <- "any string"
test_df[2,]$b <- 2
test_df[3,]$b <- format(as.Date("11-Jan-2011",format="%d-%b-%Y"), "%m/%d/%y")
print(test_df$b)
#[1] "any string" "2"          "01/11/11"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `data.frame` or `data.frame`-alike object (such as `data.table` or `tbl`). They retain the class:

```
> df <- data.frame(A=as.Date("2011-01-11") + 0:3, B=Sys.Date() + 0.3)
> sapply(df, class)
     A      B 
"Date" "Date" 
>
```

Keeping them as `Date` objets has the advantage that you can still *compute* on them. You can still convert to `character` via `format()`.

```
> df$diff <- with(df, difftime(B, A))
> df
           A          B        diff
1 2011-01-11 2021-02-06 3679.3 days
2 2011-01-12 2021-02-06 3678.3 days
3 2011-01-13 2021-02-06 3677.3 days
4 2011-01-14 2021-02-06 3676.3 days
> 
> df$diffInt <- with(df, as.integer(difftime(B, A)))
> df
           A          B        diff diffInt
1 2011-01-11 2021-02-06 3679.3 days    3679
2 2011-01-12 2021-02-06 3678.3 days    3678
3 2011-01-13 2021-02-06 3677.3 days    3677
4 2011-01-14 2021-02-06 3676.3 days    3676
>
```

Two formats as examples:

```
> df$yyymmdd <- format(df$A, "%Y%m%d")
> df$montxt <- format(df$B, "%Y-%B-%d")
> df
           A          B        diff diffInt  yyymmdd           montxt
1 2011-01-11 2021-02-06 3679.3 days    3679 20110111 2021-February-06
2 2011-01-12 2021-02-06 3678.3 days    3678 20110112 2021-February-06
3 2011-01-13 2021-02-06 3677.3 days    3677 20110113 2021-February-06
4 2011-01-14 2021-02-06 3676.3 days    3676 20110114 2021-February-06
>
```